# Spinner.setOnLongClickListener() not working in Android

Tags: android

In one of my Android's activity LongClickListener() is not working with Spinner. I have made spinner programmatically in a method which is called when Api gets hit in onCreate(). I want to enable the tdpidSpinner when it is longclicked by user.

Here's the method:

```
   public boolean setTdpId(ArrayList<String> tdpList) {
    try {
        tdpIdList = tdpList;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tdpidSpinner = new Spinner(Activity_Settings.this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams tdpid_spinner_params = new 
TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f);
                tdpidSpinner.setLayoutParams(tdpid_spinner_params);
                rowTdpid.addView(tdpidSpinner);
                tdpidSpinner.setPrompt("Select TdpId");
                tdpidSpinner.setLongClickable(true);
                tdpidSpinner.setClickable(true);


                if (tdpIdList.size() > 0) {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new 
ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            Activity_Settings.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
tdpIdList);
                    tdpidSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

                    String tdpid = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(
                            Utility.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            .getString(Utility.TDPID, "");
                    // if(tdpid!=null || tdpid!=""){

                    if (tdpid != "") {
                        int spinnerPosition = spinnerAdapter
                                .getPosition(tdpid);
                        tdpidSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
                        tdpidSpinner.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    tdpidSpinner.setOnLongClickListener(new     
  View.OnLongClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            tdpidSpinner.setEnabled(true);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Long click event will be dispatched to item view of spinner,not spinner.So if you want add longclicklistener,add it to its item view.

Comment: What does that mean? can you please explain :/

Answer (score 0):

If your `Spinner` is disabled (`tdpidSpinner.setEnabled(false);`), it won't respond to touch events.

From the `onTouchEvent` function of `View` (see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)):

```
if ((viewFlags & ENABLED_MASK) == DISABLED) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && (mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_PRESSED) != 0) {
        setPressed(false);
    }
    // A disabled view that is clickable still consumes the touch
    // events, it just doesn't respond to them.
    return (((viewFlags & CLICKABLE) == CLICKABLE || (viewFlags & LONG_CLICKABLE) == LONG_CLICKABLE));
}
```